# React passing state/props with useNavigate and updating state on the receiving component with useLocation does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I have a page `Job` with bunch of fields in a form to create a new job instance. The job once created is listed on a separate page with each instance as a `JobCard` component with summarized info. This works fine.

Now I am trying to launch the `Job` page from `JobCard` component to display all the information. So I have `onClick` function on `JobCard` that pulls all the job information from backend and pass it to `Job` page. The expected outcome is to display all the fields populated for this job instance. I am using `useNavigate` with `state` to pass the params to `Job` page. On the Job page, I am using `useLocation` to read these props.
I am receiving the props as expected however I am not able to set the local state in `Job` with these props.

I do not want to create a separate `Job` page and want to reuse the same page used to create new Job instance.

`JobCard` onClick snippet:

```
const handleJobDetails = async (e) => {
        
        try {
          const jobFetchDetails = await jobServices.getJobDetails(job.id);
    
      // compose jobs payload
      const jobProps = {
        vehicles: [],
        vehicle: jobFetchDetails.cust_info.vehicle,
        model: jobFetchDetails.cust_info.model,
        mobile: jobFetchDetails.cust_info.mobile,
        ... 
      };
      navigate("/job", { state: { jobProps: jobProps } });

    }  catch (error) {
      handleError(error);
    }
```

`Job` component (same page is used to create new job instance as well)

```
const initialValues = {
  vehicles: [],
  vehicle: "",
  model: "",
  mobile: "",
  email: "",
... } //used to reset form

export default function Job() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const {
    values,
    setvalues,
  } = useForm(initialValues); //custom hook


  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchParts = async () => {
      const partList = await partServices.fetchParts();
      setvalues((values)=> ({ ...values, parts: partList }));
    };
    fetchParts().catch((error) => handleError(error));

    // Setting state from JobCard if available
    const { state } = location;
    const { jobProps } = state || {};

    if (jobProps && jobProps.job_id) {
      // job props received

      //set state from jobProps
      setvalues((values) => ({ ...values, jobProps }));
    }
    navigate(".", {replace: true}); //reset location state
  }, [navigate]);
```

In the console logs, I can see the jobProps are correctly passed from `JobCard` to `Job`. But the state of Job component is not set with those values and so does not appear on the page. What am I doing wrong here? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that at `const { jobProps } = state || {};` that `jobProps` is the value you expect? And that after `setvalues((values) => ({ ...values, jobProps }));` the `values` state isn't updated to the value you expect? Please [edit] to clarify what the specific issue/problem is, and include all relevant code in a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the `state` was indeed getting updated correctly. The issue was in the way I was setting on `Job` side.

I changed

```
setvalues((values) => ({ ...values, jobProps }));
```

to

```
setvalues((values) => ({ ...values, ...jobProps }));
```

And it worked like a charm.

Thanks [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) for your reviewing it. I will be more precise in my future questions. Thanks.